# Cant find childs child value Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Main Activity, I check if the User is already registered to my app by searching the **whole** database for the user id (`user.getUid`), but every time (even if the user id is already saved in Database), the query cant find it.

```
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                //User is signed out
                startActivity(intentlogin);
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                finish();
            } else {

                //User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                //has user Username?
                String Userid = user.getUid();
                Query usernamequery = mRef.orderByChild("Userid").equalTo(Userid);
                usernamequery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {

                            //should go here when user id in database
                            // TODO: handle the case where the data already exists
                            return;
                        }
                        else {

                            //This is where it always lands
                            // TODO: handle the case where the data does not yet exist
                            startActivity(intentusername);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
```

This is how my Database looks like:

```
root:

Users:

customusername

       Userid:   "ondkinwakdnakjnxjexampleuseridindjan" (this it can't find!)

       Username: "customusername"
```

Comment: How is mRef initialised?

Comment: If the `mRef` like this `FirebaseDatabase().getInstance().getReference().child("Users")` then it should work

Comment: I'll add this as a comment since it's not exactly what you asked. I would suggest that you should not be structuring your data like this in the first place.

Use the UserId as the entry point to each user not the customusername! Then you completely remove the problem of trying to search for the user. Once you do `user.getUid();` you know exactly where that user should be; root -> Users -> uid. 

No searching or ordering necessary, will save you a lot of headache in the long run.

Comment: wouldnt that be the same as iam doing?

Comment: Not if I am reading your post correctly. As you've said you're searching your whole database for the id. What if you have 10,000 users? By using the userId as the key for each user you don't need to search, you don't use a Query, you just set a listener on that one node: root -> Users -> userId

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer, it works now (is there a way I can thank?) :p

Comment: i know what you mean, but i'm not exactly sure how I could pull that of, searching if a path exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, even if you are querying a single item, a query always returns a list of values. Iterate through these values.

```
Query usernamequery = mRef.orderByChild("Userid").equalTo(Userid);
                    usernamequery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot != null && snapshot.getChildren != null) {

                                //Define a model class for user that contains UserId and Username
                                for(DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                                    Model model = child.getValue(Model.class);

                                    //now, get the UserId and username from the model class

                                model.getUserId();

                            }
                        }
                        else {

                            //This is where it always lands
                            // TODO: handle the case where the data does not yet exist
                            startActivity(intentusername);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This might not be the best answer for me in the moment but it comes in handy in another class (username taken or not) thanks